# Angular js :unexpected token error shown in android studio console,but works fine in browser

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I've a strange problem in my cordova android project(angularjs+ionic),when i am running project in android studio i will get this error on my js file.

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {, http://192.168.43.211:8100/templates/todo/js/controllers.js, Line: 184
```

but when i run same file  in google chrome  i will get the resul and no error is shown

Here is the codeblock of the error  message

```
$scope.todos = $scope.todos.map(({text, status,note,create_date,to_do_id}) => {
             var ch;
             if(status=='1') ch=true; else ch=false;
             console.log(ch);
                return {
                  text,
                  flag:ch,
                  note:note,
                  to_do_id:to_do_id,
                  create_date:create_date,
                  status:status
                  };
              });
```

When i hide the above code block no error is shown in android studio console,but i need the above code block to complete the functionality.

What is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primary solution**

Are you sure that your mobile browser supports JS arrow expressions? They were introduced in ECMAScript 6 so some of the browsers may still have no support for them. Try changing the arrow expression into an anonymous function:

```
$scope.todos = $scope.todos.map(function(record) {
    var ch;
    if (record.status == '1') ch = true; else ch = false;
    console.log(ch);
    return {
        text: record.text,
        flag: ch,
        note: record.note,
        to_do_id: record.to_do_id,
        create_date: record.create_date,
        status: record.status
    };
});
```

---

**Alternative solution**

If the above code would still not work, you can always create your own map function:

```
function _arrayMap(array, callback) {
    var newArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray.push(callback(array[i]));
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

And use it in similar way:

```
$scope.todos = _arrayMap($scope.todos, function(record) {
    var ch;
    if (record.status == '1') ch = true; else ch = false;
    console.log(ch);
    return {
        text: record.text,
        flag: ch,
        note: record.note,
        to_do_id: record.to_do_id,
        create_date: record.create_date,
        status: record.status
    };
});
```

Comment: Let me try your answer

Comment: Now the error is gone,but `$scope.todos`  value is printed as string.

Comment: My bad, I forgot that `map` function's syntax is a bit different when using anonymous function. I edited my answer - it should now work as expected.

Comment: I've also added an alternative solution if the one above would still not work